# Finding linear equation for the plane of equidistant point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to do some practice questions in my book and I encountered this question:

Find a linear equation for the plane consisting of all point $(x,y,z)$ in space that are equidistant from the origin and the point $(2,2,2)$.

The answer key for the book gives me the solution:

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = (x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (z-2)^2$

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x^2 - 4x + 4 + y^2- 4y +4 +z^2 -4z +4$

$x + y + z = 3$

Can someone please explain how this solution works? Where does $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ come from? And what does equating it to the right equation do? Can you please assume I'm starting to learn Calc 3 when explaining? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the distance formula, the distance between the point $(x,y,z)$ and the origin $(0,0,0)$ is:

$$\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-0)^2}$$

Using the distance formula, the distance between the point $(x,y,z)$ and the origin $(2,2,2)$ is:

$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2}$$

Hence, $(x,y,z)$ is equidistant from the origin and $(2,2,2)$ if and only if these distances are equal:

$$\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-0)^2} = \sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2}$$

Now, square both sides and simplify to get the equation of the plane. That is what your book did.

Comment: How do I know that the result is the equation of the plane? I only used the distance formula. Is there an equation that relates the distance formula to the equation of the plane?